# Objective-C OpenGL Animation in Sample GLPaint code

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, opengl-es

I am digging into the sample project created by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

It demonstrates how to use OpenGL in Objective-C.

When I start the app a "SHAKE ME" graph is drawn stroke by stroke, with animation. As I want to modify this project to make my own app, in `PaintingView.m`, I want to know how to **disable the animation** whenever I call the 
`renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:`
method (specifically, in the `playback:` function, because in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` the animation is unnoticeable).

**That is, I want to write a `renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:animated:` method such that, if I put `NO` after `animated:`, the line would be drawn instantly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

All I have to do is, in

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
```

silence the two lines at the end:

```
// Display the buffer
// glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
// [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

And after the whole graph are drawn onto the buffer, call this two lines to display the whole graph; it will appear instantly.